# Access token from client_credentials flow results in 401 Authorization Required

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have an application load balancer in front of an ECS cluster. The cluster contains a containerised service with a graphql endpoint that I would like to call via client code. I am using AWS Cognito to secure the load balancer.

I'm following the `client_credentials` flow from this [aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/) because the call will be made from a server side application.

Request the access token:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://<MYDOMAIN>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYCLIENTSECRET&scope=MY_CUSTOM_SCOPE&redirect_uri=https://MYDOMAIN.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Which returns.

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJraWQiO.....IPV7sAAb-qg",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

I then send the access token:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://MYLOADBALANCERDOMAIN/graphql' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJraWQiO......IPV7sAAb-qg' \
--data-raw ''
```

But get a 401 Unauthorized.

```xml
<html>

<head>
    <title>401 Authorization Required</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>401 Authorization Required</h1>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

I have also tried using `aws cognito-idp initiate-auth ...` to get a token and send it to the same graphql endpoint, which doesn't work either. I've tried including the scope in the request to the graphql endpoint as

`https://MYLOADBALANCERDOMAIN/graphql/RESOURCE_SERVER_IDENTIFIER/SCOPE_NAME`

or

`https://MYLOADBALANCERDOMAIN/graphql?scope=RESOURCE_SERVER_IDENTIFIER/SCOPE_NAME`

I should get the token from the user pool, send it to and have it validated by the resource server, which should then pass my request on to the `/graphql` path behind the load balancer. Am I misunderstanding the flow? Why doesn't the access token authorize me to call the backend service?

**Update**
Decoded JWT:

```json
{
  "sub": "5vritit87vn2er09i273bbqn5n",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "testapp.development/access",
  "auth_time": 1634204524,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_<mypool-id>",
  "exp": 1634208124,
  "iat": 1634204524,
  "version": 2,
  "jti": "3f6f07d0-6619-4102-b122-06011d6a421f",
  "client_id": "my-client-id"
}
```

Header:

```json
{
  "kid": "RGC+2g3UG90bRMypnTs49Gl9X3XYF2QZ/dAFsArHRNk=",
  "alg": "RS256"
}
```

Comment: What scopes are you sending in the request? Decode the JWT using https://jwt.io/ - what are the scopes returned inside?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I have updated the question with the decoded JWT

Comment: Thank you - what scopes are you sending in the request?

Comment: curl --location --request GET 'https://MYLOADBALANCERDOMAIN/graphql?scope=testapp.development/access' \

Comment: Change your initial request URL for getting the token to `...&scope=MY_CUSTOM_SCOPE,openid&...` - does that change anything?

Comment: I get `{"error": "invalid_scope"}` probably because `openid` is not supported when you use the `client_credentials` flow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238133/discussion-between-ermiya-eskandary-and-puffin).